# Is it bad to write object oriented C?

Tags: c

I always seem to write code in C that is mostly object oriented, so say I had a source file or something I would create a struct then pass the pointer to this struct to functions (methods) owned by this structure:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
};

struct foo* createFoo(); // mallocs foo

void destroyFoo(struct foo* foo); // frees foo and its things
```

Is this bad practice? How do I learn to write C the "proper way".

Comment: Much of Linux (the kernel) is written this way, in fact it even emulates even more OO-like concepts like virtual method dispatch. I consider that pretty proper.

Comment: @KilianFoth Glad to hear, I've been programming C for a while now and I thought I was "doing it wrong"

Comment: "_[T]he determined Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language._" - [Ed Post, 1983](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to switch to C++? You don't have to use the parts of it that you don't like.

Comment: This really begs the question of, "What is 'object oriented'?" I wouldn't call this object oriented. I would say it's procedural. (You have no inheritance, no polymorphism, no encapsulation/ability to hide state, and are probably missing other hallmarks of OO that aren't coming off the top of my head.) Whether it's good or bad practice is not dependent on those semantics, though.

Comment: @jpmc26: You are right with your question about object orientation. Hiding state is possible if you use opaque types, disabling access of functions from other "classes" can be avoided by using static functions and one file per type, interitance is also possible (see chapter 4 of https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf).

Comment: @svick I'm not sure, I write C++ every now and then and I can write C++, I just prefer not to it's too complicated I can't seem to find time to learn its ins and outs, though I have been looking at strousups core cpp guidelines on GitHub which are interesting. Though nowadays when I program I use something like D, or Go.

Comment: @jpmc26: If you are a linguistic prescriptivist, you should listen to Alan Kay, he invented the term, he gets to say what it means, and he says [OOP is all about Messaging](http://www.purl.org/stefan_ram/pub/doc_kay_oop_en). If you are a linguistic descriptivist, you would survey the usage of the term in the software development community. Cook did exactly that, he analyzed the features of languages that either claim to or are considered to be OO, and [he found that they have one thing in common: Messaging](http://wcook.blogspot.com/2012/07/proposal-for-simplified-modern.html).

Comment: @jpmc26: "no polymorphism" you can use function pointers in structs, "no encapsulation/ability to hide state": use opaque data types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).

Comment: @Giorgio The style demonstrated in the question defines functions separately from the `struct`, so that doesn't seem to be a viable option here. I'll give you encapsulation, though. Although, as I stated above, the issue of whether it's OO or not isn't really relevant to whether it's a good idea.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This really just shifts the question: "What is 'messaging'?" I really don't see anything in the question I would call "messaging." There's not multiple entities passing messages between one another. The structure here suggests some external sequence of code calling each function in turn. If this is considered object oriented, then I think you would have a hard time distinguishing the object oriented paradigm from procedural or functional paradigms. To be fair, maybe that wasn't a distinction Kay ever intended, but then it makes even less sense to label things with it.

Comment: @jpmc26: In modern speak, that's *virtual method dispatch* or *vtable dispatch*. However, I dislike those terms, because they focus on the implementation mechanism, not the metaphor. To me, the constituent parts are a) polymorphism, which is b) ad-hoc and c) happens at runtime. That's also what Cook identifies. All the other things are either orthogonal (e.g. inheritance) or follow naturally (if all you can do is send messages and observe their responses, data hiding and data abstraction fall out naturally). This means that for example classes in Java are *not* object-oriented (they describe …

Comment: … *Abstract Data Types*, not objects, but interfaces are), it also means that lambda-calculus, and by extension functional languages (or rather closures) *are* object-oriented, at least in the sense that you can implement data abstraction with closures and have a closure with a selector function that closes over some other closures, which all close over some shared closure simulate an object. As to C, I simply don't know enough about it, to judge how "direct" an encoding of OO can be. Do you have to build a full-on Smalltalk interpreter? Can you get by with a couple of `void*` structs of …

Comment: … function pointers? I don't know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, this is not bad practice, it is even encouraged to do so, although one could even use conventions like `struct foo *foo_new();` and `void foo_free(struct foo *foo);`

Of course, as a comment says, only do this where appropriate. There is no sense in using a constructor for an `int`.

The prefix `foo_` is a convention followed by a lot of libraries, because it guards against clashing with naming of other libraries. Other functions often have the convention to use `foo_<function>(struct foo *foo, <parameters>);`. This allows your `struct foo` to be an opaque type.

Have a look at the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for the convention, especially with "subnamespaces", so that calling a function `curl_multi_*` looks wrong at first sight when the first parameter was returned by `curl_easy_init()`.

There are even more generic approaches, see [Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

Comment: Always with the caveat "where appropriate". OOP is not a silver-bullet.

Comment: Doesn't C have namespaces wherein you could declare these functions? Similar to `std::string`, couldn't you have `foo::create`? I don't use C. Maybe that's only in C++?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice There are no namespaces in C, that's why many library authors use prefixes for their functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not bad, it's excellent. Object Oriented Programming is a good thing (unless you get carried away, you *can* have too much of a good thing). C is not the most suitable language for OOP, but that shouldn't stop you getting the best out of it.

Comment: Not that I can disagree, but your opinion really should be supported by *some* elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad. It endorses to use **RAII** which prevents many bugs ( memory leaks, using uninitialized variables, use after free etc. which can cause security issues ).

So, if you want to compile your code only with GCC or Clang ( and not with MS compiler ), you can use `cleanup` attribute, that will properly destruct your objects. If you declare your object like that:

```
my_str __attribute__((cleanup(my_str_destructor))) ptr;
```

Then `my_str_destructor(ptr)` will be run when ptr goes out of scope. Just keep in mind, that it cannot be used with [function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383695/why-cleanup-attribute-of-gcc-clang-can-not-be-used-with-function-parameter).

Also, remember to use `my_str_` in your method names, because `C` does not have namespaces, and it's easy to collide with some other function name.

Comment: Afaik, RAII is about using the implicit calling of destructors for objects in C++ to ensure cleanup, avoiding the need to add explicit resource release calls. So, if I'm not much mistaken, RAII and C are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @cmaster If you `#define` your typenames to use `__attribute__((cleanup(my_str_destructor)))` then you will get it as implicit in whole `#define` scope ( it will be added to all your variable declarations ).

Comment: That works if a) you use gcc, b) if you use the type only in function local variables, and c) if you use the type only in a naked version (no pointers to the `#define`'d type or arrays of it). In short: It's not standard C, and you pay with a lot of inflexibility in use.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, that also works in clang.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. That indeed makes the requirement a) significantly less severe, as that makes `__attribute__((cleanup()))` pretty much a quasi-standard. However, b) and c) still stand...

Comment: solution for b) is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21384435/898435) and for c) you can #define those pointers/arrays

Comment: There's also a library that uses this attribute to implement C++ shared_ptr/unique_ptr in C - https://github.com/Snaipe/libcsptr

Answer (score -2):

There can be many advantages to such code, but unfortunately the C Standard was not written to facilitate it.  Compilers have historically offered effective behavioral guarantees beyond what the Standard required that made it possible to write such code much more cleanly than is possible in Standard C, but compilers have lately started revoking such guarantees in the name of optimization.

Most notably, many C compilers have historically guaranteed (by design if not documentation) that if two structure types contain the same initial sequence, a pointer to either type may be used to access members of that common sequence, even if the types are unrelated, and further that for purposes of establishing a common initial sequence all pointers to structures are equivalent.  Code which makes use of such behavior can be much cleaner and more type-safe than code which does not, but unfortunately even though the Standard requires that structures sharing a common initial sequence must be laid out the same way, it forbids code from actually using a pointer of one type to access the initial sequence of another.

Consequently, if you want to write object-oriented code in C, you'll have to decide (and should make this decision early on) to either jump through a lot of hoops to abide by C's pointer-type rules and be prepared to have modern compilers generate nonsensical code if one slips up, even if older compilers would have generated code which works as intended, or else document a requirement that the code will only be usable with compilers that are configured to support old-style pointer behavior (e.g. using an "-fno-strict-aliasing")  Some people regard "-fno-strict-aliasing" as evil, but I would suggest that it is more helpful to think of "-fno-strict-aliasing" C as being a language which offers greater semantic power for some purposes than "standard" C, but at the expense of optimizations which might be important for some other purposes.

By means of example, on traditional compilers, historical compilers would interpret the following code:

```
struct pair { int i1,i2; };
struct trio { int i1,i2,i3; };

void hey(struct pair *p, struct trio *t)
{
  p->i1++;
  t->i1^=1;
  p->i1--;
  t->i1^=1;
}
```

as performing the following steps in order: increment the first member of `*p`, complement the lowest bit of the first member of `*t`, then decrement the first member of `*p`, and complement the lowest bit of the first member of `*t`.  Modern compilers will rearrange the sequence of operations in a fashion which code which will be more efficient if `p` and `t` identify different objects, but will change the behavior if they don't.

This example is of course deliberately contrived, and in practice code which uses a pointer of one type to access members that are part of the common initial sequence of another type will *usually* work, but unfortunately since there's no way of knowing when such code might fail it's not possible to safely use it at all except by disabling type-based aliasing analysis.

A somewhat less contrived example would occur if one wanted to write a function to do something like swap two pointers to arbitrary types.  In the vast majority of "1990s C" compilers, that could be accomplished via:

```
void swap_pointers(void **p1, void **p2)
{
  void *temp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = temp;
}
```

In Standard C, however, one would have to use:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
void swap_pointers2(void **p1, void **p2)
{
  void **temp = malloc(sizeof (void*));
  memcpy(temp, p1, sizeof (void*));
  memcpy(p1, p2, sizeof (void*));
  memcpy(p2, temp, sizeof (void*));
  free(temp);
}
```

If `*p2` is kept in allocated storage, and the temporary pointer isn't kept in allocated storage, the effective type of `*p2` will become the type of the temporary pointer, and code which attempts to use `*p2` as any type which didn't match the temporary-pointer type will invoke Undefined Behavior.  It is to be sure extremely unlikely that a compiler would notice such a thing, but since modern compiler philosophy require that programmers avoid Undefined Behavior at all cost, I can't think of any other safe means of writing the above code without using allocated storage.

Comment: Downvoters: Care to comment?  A key aspect of object-oriented programming is the ability to have multiple types share common aspects, and have a pointer to any such type be usable to access those common aspects.  The OP's example doesn't do that, but it's barely scratching the surface of being "object-oriented".  Historical C compilers would allow polymorphic code to be written in a much cleaner fashion than is possible in today's standard C.  Designing object-oriented code in C thus requires that one determine what exact language one is targeting.  With what aspect to people disagree?

Comment: Hm... mind you show how the guarantees the standard gives don't allow you to cleanly access members of the common initial sub-sequence? Because I think that's what your rant about the evils of daring to optimize within the bounds of contractual behavior hinges on this time? (That's *my* guess what the two downvoters found objectionable.)

Comment: OOP does not necessarily require inheritance, so compatibility between two structs isn't much of an issue in practice. I can get real OO by putting function pointers into a struct, and invoking those functions in a particular manner. Of course, this `foo_function(foo*, ...)` pseudo-OO in C is just a particular API style that happens to look like classes, but it should more properly be called modular programming with abstract data types.

Comment: @Deduplicator: See the indicated example.  Field "i1" is a member of the common initial sequence of both structures, but modern compilers will fail if code tries to use a "struct pair*" to access the initial member of a "struct trio".

Comment: Which modern C compiler fails that example? Any interesting options needed?

Comment: See http://goo.gl/zV5FQw for an on-line compiler tester with the code pre-loaded.  In case you don't understand assembly code, `bx lr` is the ARM equivalent of "return", so the compiler optimizes the function down to nothing.

Comment: ;-) Look where I just was: https://goo.gl/WxKrZO -O2 or more seems to break it...

Comment: I think that's simply a compiler-bug though. Will look at it a bit more tomorrow.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Under a reasonable reading of the Standard, there would be no way to pass the code above two pointers to the same object without invoking Undefined Behavior, and consequently a compiler would be justified in doing whatever it likes.  I think the C89 rules were badly written but the common interpretations of them allowed useful optimizations while allowing programmers to do anything that could be done in their absence.  Modern philosophy, however, suggests that compiler writers should feel no obligation to go beyond what a compiler-friendly reading of the standard would require.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Consider also how one would write a function which, given two pointers to pointers of arbitrary type, will swap them (see above).  Having to use `malloc` to create temporary storage seems absurd, but I don't think the Standard allows any alternative. [Note: rather than treating the pointers as `void*` the function should treat them as `struct DUMMY_TYPE*`, since structure pointers are allowed to have a different size from `void*`; violations of the type rules, however, result in UB even when all pointers are the same size].

Answer (score -3):

Next step is to hide the struct declaration.  You put this in the .h file:

```
typedef struct foo_s foo_t;

foo_t * foo_new(...);
void foo_destroy(foo_t *foo);
some_type foo_whatever(foo_t *foo, ...);
...
```

And then in the .c file:

```
struct foo_s {
    ...
};
```

Comment: That might be the next step, depending on the aim. Whether it is or not, this doesn't even remotely try to answer the question though.